# Node JS scalable server with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, node.js, scalability

I am trying to achieve scalable production server that combines Node JS and MSSQL vis [node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). At its simplest implementation, it requires listening to 5000 concurrent clients ( modems ) which will send information every 5 seconds " not necessarily at the same time". The server will process and store the data within an SQL database. To achieve this, a simulation clients script is created below. It works fine at the limit of few hundreds clients. Above that, error below displays:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET     //alternatively it s a 'write'
    at errnoException (net.js:900:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:555:19)
```

The client is:

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 8901;

var clients = [];

for (var i=0; i <  100  ; i++ )
{

 var socket  = new net.Socket();
 socket.connect(PORT, HOST, function() { });    
 clients.push(socket);  

 }
writeThings();


function writeThings()
{
// var starting= new Date().getTime()  ;
for (var c=0; c <  clients.length    ; c++)
{
    clients[c].write('message from: ' + c + ',message text' );
    //clients[c].end();
}
 //var ending = new Date().getTime() ; 
    //console.log(ending - starting);
    setTimeout(writeThings, 5000);
}
```

The server code:

```
var sql = require('mssql'); 
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 8901;

var sqlconfig = 
{
user: ' ',
password: ' ',
server: ' ',  
database: ' ...' ,
pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 20,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3000
     }
} // end sql config

var connection = new sql.Connection(sqlconfig, function(err) {});
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
request.stream = true;

net.createServer(function(sock) {
sock.on('data', function(unitMessage) {  

console.log(sock.remoteAddress + ' : ' + sock.remotePort + ' : ' +    unitMessage.toString());
  console.log('\r\n');
  request.input('message', sql.VarChar(120) , unitMessage);
  request.execute('updateSkyLog', function(err, recordsets, returnValue) {     /* you can do things here  */ }); 
  request.on('error', function(err) { console.log('Error: ' + err.message);        }); 


 });

 sock.on('close',function(client){ console.log('connection closed by client'); });
 sock.on('error' , function(){ console.log('error on connection')});

 }).listen(PORT, HOST);

 console.log('Server started ... @' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
```

Any pointing to real world script that can handle this amount of clients and data is appreciated.